# Munin Postgres plugins: DBD::Pg not found

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, perl, munin

I'm trying to activate some of the Postgresql plugins for Munin. When I run `munin-node-configure --suggest | grep postgres` I get the following output:

```
postgres_bgwriter          | no   | no [DBD::Pg not found, and cannot do psql yet]
postgres_cache_            | no   | no [DBD::Pg not found, and cannot do psql yet]
postgres_checkpoints       | no   | no [DBD::Pg not found, and cannot do psql yet]
postgres_connections_      | no   | no [DBD::Pg not found, and cannot do psql yet]
postgres_connections_db    | no   | no [DBD::Pg not found, and cannot do psql yet]
postgres_locks_            | no   | no [DBD::Pg not found, and cannot do psql yet]
postgres_querylength_      | no   | no [DBD::Pg not found, and cannot do psql yet]
postgres_scans_            | no   | no [DBD::Pg not found, and cannot do psql yet]
postgres_size_             | no   | no [DBD::Pg not found, and cannot do psql yet]
postgres_transactions_     | no   | no [DBD::Pg not found, and cannot do psql yet]
```

I've Googled around for an answer but haven't found any definitive answer for how to solve this problem. I've never worked with Perl modules before (all our software is in Python) so what would I need to do to install this dependency? I'm using Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Many perl modules will be available within the usual package hierarchy. For Ubuntu, I believe the package you want is  called `libdbd-pg-perl` - so try installing that with:

```
sudo apt install libdbd-pg-perl
```

For packages not included within the package hierarchy, you can use the perl module CPAN to install them. As root, run

```
perl -MCPAN -eshell
```

and follow the instructions to configure what sites to download perl modules from. Once the configuration is done, type

```
install DBD::PG
```

to install the module and any modules it depends on.

Comment: Great thanks! `apt-get install libdbd-pg-perl` solved it.

Comment: ```apt-get install libdbd-pg-perl``` worked for me as well!